# Heroku can't find module

Tags: node.js, heroku, total.js

I'm new with heroku. I've being following the tutorial for deploying node on heroku. In fact, I'm trying to deply total.js eshop on heroku... but I can't solve the following error.

```
2018-10-28T10:08:58.151845+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node debug.js`
2018-10-28T10:09:00.188338+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:550
2018-10-28T10:09:00.188370+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-10-28T10:09:00.188372+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-10-28T10:09:00.188374+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-28T10:09:00.188376+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'node_modules/total.js/debug.js'
2018-10-28T10:09:00.188377+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
```

This is the code from the initial point of access

```
require('node_modules/total.js/debug.js')(options);
```

I've checked that my folder structure exits, but let me say that I've modified the above code.

It used to be

```
require(total.js/debug')(options);
```

and it worked locally.

Could it be this related to the fact that I've installed locally this, but this is not executed in heroku?

```
install $ npm install total.js
install $ npm install paypal-express-checkout
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is older [Total.js example for Heroku](https://github.com/totaljs/examples/tree/master/heroku). Maybe it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've already read this article, but it's basic and it's not helping too much. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed correct version of Total.js? I think that Total.js isn't installed on Heroku....

Comment: Should I? I mean.... this is on my json dependencies...   },
  "dependencies": {
    "paypal-express-checkout": "latest",
    "total.js": "latest"
  },

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pathfile problem. Try removing the /node_modules from your "require", or do it with a relative path i.e.:

`"./node_modules/total.js"`

Comment: Thanks....  Removing the /node_modules is how the default file is configured, but this is not working. I've tried as you mentioned, because I agree that it seems that it a pathfile problem, but I can't get with it. "./node_modules/total.js/debug" is neither working.